# "GeomFromText" Not store in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have try to save data into table in CI

Like:

$geomatchinfo = array
(

```
[Latitude] => 45.8556528
[Longitude] => 22.9565858
[Geom] => GeomFromText('Point(45.855653 22.956586)')
[Radius] => 15.0
[Mode] => white
[Name] => dsad
[Description] => asd
[Formatted] => asdasd, Deva, Romania
[Address] => a:5:{s:7:"address";s:6:"asdasd";s:5:"route";s:6:"asdasd";s:4:"city";s:4:"Deva";s:5:"state";s:9:"Hunedoara";s:7:"country";s:7:"Romania";}
```

)

Geomatch::create($geomatchinfo);

but its give me error like

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message '22003, 1416, Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tr-fresh\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php:312

I have database fields name "Geom" datatype "geometry".

Comment: Because CI sends `GeomFromText('Point(45.855653 22.956586)')` *as text* to the database, i.e. `INSERT INTO ... 'GeomFromText(\'Point(45.855653 22.956586)\')'`. And that's not a valid geometry. The query needs to look like `INSERT INTO ... GeomFromText('Point(45.855653 22.956586)')`; no idea how to do this using CI's DAL, since I don't know CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested to use function in insert query in CI, you need to use set method separately for insert

`GeomFromText('Point(45.855653 22.956586)')`

And you have to pass third parameter as false in set method of CI. like this.

```
$this->db->set("Geom", "GeomFromText('Point(45.855653 22.956586)')", FALSE);
```

May be it could be help full for you.